# How can be defined a sql query for an average in timeranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have following table in postgresql:

**id** as bigint | **visitors** as integer | **timestamp** as timestamp with time zone

I want to calculate average number of visitors e.g. for these time range: monday from 8am-9am, monday from 9am-10am  and so on (for whole week). How can i do it via sql query? I try to do it with functions like: EXTRACT but without success.

I'm gonna have another problem because I have to take holidays into account. But this will be the next step (or problem).

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does "average" mean in this case?  Average of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a sample like this one :

```
create table visit
(
    idvisit serial
    , idvisitor int
    , dh_visite timestamp
);

insert into visit (idvisitor, dh_visite)
values
    (1, '24/10/2019 10:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (1, '24/10/2019 14:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (1, '24/10/2019 14:30:23'::timestamp)
    , (2, '24/10/2019 10:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (2, '24/10/2019 14:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (2, '24/10/2019 16:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (1, '25/10/2019 09:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (1, '25/10/2019 10:20:23'::timestamp)
    , (3, '25/10/2019 10:40:23'::timestamp)
    , (3, '25/10/2019 10:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (1, '26/10/2019 23:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (1, '26/10/2019 22:00:23'::timestamp)
    , (2, '26/10/2019 11:00:23'::timestamp);
```

You can have the number of visit per hour per day like this :

```
with cte as 
(
    select * 
        , to_char(dh_visite, 'day') as day_of_week
        , extract(hour from dh_visite) as strict_hour_of_visit
    from visit
)
select 
    day_of_week
    , strict_hour_of_visit
    , count(*) as nb_visit
from cte
group by day_of_week
    , strict_hour_of_visit
order by 1,2;
```

After that you can do any customization on your fields (like put the hour in english format and so on).